# WinForms WebBrowser control not loading whole site

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using `WebBrowser` in C# to display the website that contains login form. After I logged in successfully some parts of the website are not shown in the `WebBrowser` but in the default browser the same site is showing correctly.

Another issue is when I click on the link in `WebBrowser` it opens up in the default browser like (Firefox,chrome...etc ).

My application set the username and password automatically for login .

```
ChangeUserAgent();
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(loadLinks(namewebsite));
string useragent = request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.79 Safari/537.36 Edge/14.14393";
webBrowser2.Navigate(request.RequestUri,null,null, "User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.79 Safari/537.36 Edge/14.14393");
loadauthintication(namewebsite, _username, _password);
```

it is the method loadauthintication

```
using (var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
        {
            var json = webClient.DownloadString(@"http://example.com/getauthintication.php?name="+name+"&user="+user+"&pass="+pass);
            // Now parse with JSON.Net
           // MessageBox.Show(json);
            string[] array = json.Split('~');
            username = array[0];
            password = array[1];

        }
```

method

```
public void ChangeUserAgent()
    {
       ua = "Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.google.com/bot.html)";

        UrlMkSetSessionOption(URLMON_OPTION_USERAGENT_REFRESH, null, 0, 0);
        UrlMkSetSessionOption(URLMON_OPTION_USERAGENT, ua, ua.Length, 0);
    }
```

Comment: What is a windows forums browser?

Comment: webBrowser componenet in c#

Comment: Show some more code, screenshots of how it looks now and how it should look like, etc.

Comment: i edited the question  put some more sourse code , and if it is ok i can send to your email .

Comment: @LoanDone, I've answered regarding the mis-rendering of the page; you should really ask a separate question regarding the links opening in a different browser as that's quite a different question! =)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the `WebBrowser` [control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser(v=vs.110).aspx) is that by default it renders output in  IE7 rendering mode. Rick Strahl has written a [very detailed post](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/May/21/Web-Browser-Control-Specifying-the-IE-Version) that covers some of the ways you can work around this.

The way I've usually used is to modify the registry by creating a new key at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION` which is named for the executable for the application (e.g. `ConsoleApplication1.exe`) and setting the value to be that of the version of Internet Explorer I know will be installed in the target environment - for me that's always been IE11 - a value of 11001.

**NOTE**: As Rick mentions in his post, bear in mind that when run through Visual Studio, the name of your exe may/will be `ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe` so you'll need to add a registry key for that